# Can't work out the logic for formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two cells and I want to write a formula to check two conditions and return "Error" if either condition is met. The conditions are;

1.Are both the cells empty?

2.Are both cells NOT empty?

(It should only return OK if ONE of the cells is empty and the other contains something.

So far I have tried the following;

`=IF(X25=""*AD25=""+X25<>""*AD25<>"","Error","OK")`

And also;

`=IF(X25=""*AD25="","Error",IF(X25<>""*AD25<>"","Error","OK")`

With either of these attempts I get a `#VALUE` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some [conditional formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-conditional-formulas-HP005251012.aspx), like this -

```
 =IF(AND(A17<>"",B17<>""),"ERROR",IF(OR(A17<>"",B17<>""),"OK","ERROR"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try using the `COUNTA()` formula. It counts non-empty cells within a given range.

```
=IF(COUNTA(X25,AD25)=1,"OK","Error")
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the end result you want, CallumDS33’s answer is very good. 
But, if you want something like what you tried, here’s a short, tricky way:

```
=IF((X25="")=(AD25=""), "Error", "OK")
```

In words:

- Check whether `X25` is blank.
- Check whether `AD25` is blank.
- If the above conditions evaluate to the same Boolean value
  (i.e., both TRUE or both FALSE), then report “Error”, otherwise report “OK”.